# Chainlink Node Operation on the Polygon Mainnet

Tags: chainlink

Doing my research on Chainlink node operation and getting ready to spin up a node, I see the docs, or at least the ones I found, show setting up for eth but I was curious about setting up and maintaining a node for the Polygon mainnet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow [Running a Chainlink Node](https://docs.chain.link/docs/running-a-chainlink-node/) step by step tutorial and then adjust parameters for Polygon mainnet like this

```
echo "ROOT=/chainlink
LOG_LEVEL=debug
ETH_CHAIN_ID=137
MIN_OUTGOING_CONFIRMATIONS=2
LINK_CONTRACT_ADDRESS=0xb0897686c545045afc77cf20ec7a532e3120e0f1
CHAINLINK_TLS_PORT=0
SECURE_COOKIES=false
GAS_UPDATER_ENABLED=true
ALLOW_ORIGINS=*" > ~/.chainlink-polygon/.env
```

To adjust variables for other chains in the future visit [Developer Reference Page](https://docs.chain.link/docs/link-token-contracts/)

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking for!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: I am wondering if you have experience setting up the nodes on ubuntu based OS. I am snagging on the postgresql and when I try to start the node, i get I a permission denied when trying to connect to the docker daemon